# How to define a Diagrams backend that combines several primitive backends

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I would like to make the same program use two different [Diagrams](https://diagrams.github.io/) backends, notably [diagrams-rasterific](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-rasterific) to generate PNGs, and [diagrams-svg](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-svg) to generate SVGs, from the same diagram. Since Diagrams seems to be designed around using a single backend, I'm trying to define a composed backend, but am running into trouble defining `renderToTree` for the [`Backend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Types.html#t:Backend) instance:

```
import Diagrams.Core
import Diagrams.Core.Types

import qualified Diagrams.Backend.Rasterific as BackendA
import qualified Diagrams.Backend.SVG as BackendB

tokenA :: BackendA.B
tokenA = BackendA.Rasterific

tokenB :: BackendB.B
tokenB = BackendB.SVG

data Multi = Multi
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

type B = Multi

data MultiResult n = MultiResult (Result BackendA.B V2 n) (Result BackendB.B V2 n)
-- alternatively:
-- data MultiResult n =
--     ResultA (Result BackendA.B V2 n)
--   | ResultB (Result BackendB.B V2 n)

type instance V Multi = V2
type instance N Multi = Double

instance (TypeableFloat n, Show n) => Backend Multi V2 n where
  data Render Multi V2 n =
      RenderMulti
          { renderA :: Render BackendA.B V2 n
          , renderB :: Render BackendB.B V2 n
          }
  -- alternatively:
  -- data Render Multi V2 n =
  --     RenderA (renderA :: Render BackendA.B V2 n)
  --   | RenderB (renderB :: Render BackendB.B V2 n)

  type Result Multi V2 n = MultiResult n

  data Options Multi V2 n = MultiOptions

  renderRTree _ o tree = MultiResult
      (renderRTree tokenA (toOptA o) (treeToA tree))
      (renderRTree tokenB (toOptB o) (treeToB tree))
```

I'm unclear of how to defer to the individual backend implementations' `renderRTree` functions here. In either alternative structure (with the Render and Result types as sums or products), I'm failing to make the types match up. Concretely, in this approach, I'm stuck at

```
treeToA :: RTree Multi V2 n a -> RTree BackendA.B V2 n a
treeToA = fmap f
  where
    f (RAnnot a) = RAnnot a
    f (RStyle s) = RStyle s
    f REmpty = REmpty
    f (RPrim x) = RPrim (toA x)

toA :: Prim Multi V2 n -> Prim BackendA.B V2 n
toA = ???
```

but I'm not that confident this is even the way to go.

`toOptA`, `toOptB` aren't a problem, I can fill those in once they're needed. I can also provide `Renderable` instance for this backend with either approach, e.g.

```
instance (Show n, TypeableFloat n) => Renderable (Path V2 n) Multi where
  render _ x = RenderMulti (render tokenA x) (render tokenB x)
```

Comment: Why are you defining a new backend? Why not just call `renderDia` (or whatever) at two different types in your program?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not completely sure. Chances are that I couldn't get things to type check without a concrete backend type back when I tried that approach. Knowing that's the default correct approach(?), I'll give it another shot. I'm still curious how/whether the composed backend would work though.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with other-Daniel about keeping the `Diagram` polymorphic and using it at two types.  Something like:

```
dia :: forall b. (Renderable (Path V2 Double) b, V b ~ V2, N b ~ Double) => Diagram b
dia = circle 1
```

The type sigs will only get worse as you add primitive types, so I'd probably define a constraint for all the primitives I want:

```
type Back b = (V b ~ V2, N b ~ Double, 
    Renderable (Path V2 Double) b, Renderable (Text Double) b)

dia2 :: Back b => Diagram b
dia2 = circle 1 # fc blue
```

I don't think we can write `renderRTree` for your `Multi` and have it type-check.  We expect that *all* the instances of `Renderable _ Multi` will be of the form `(Renderable p SVG, Renderable p Rasterific) => Renderable p Multi`, which should be enough to write `toA`.  But we can't (AFAIK) promise this to GHC, because `Renderable` is an open type class.

Comment: I wonder why this awesome `Back` constraint synonym is not in the `diagrams` package yet.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why is there `Renderable (Text Double) b` there. What benefit does it add?

Comment: My point was that each program can define a type alias to suit its local needs. I frequently need Text, and usually use Double, but a program with different needs can use only the constraints it needs.